# iOS programatic Cellular Data Control

Tags: ios, swift, networking, settings

Is there a way to programmatically access the "Cellular Data" options that are sometimes shown in apps?

#### Background

I have an application that uploads data files over the internet.  I have given users the option of disabling this upload functionality when not connected to WiFi.

#### How

What I'm currently doing is I wrote a `settings.bundle` that allows the user to select an option called **User Cellular Data** in my code I am using a `Reachability.swift` file from (https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) - which is a swift wrapper around the reachability iOS api - basically it can tell you if there is Wifi or cellular network access.

#### My code

In my code before doing uploads I check a NSUserDefaults value (as set by the `settings.bundle`)

```
let uploadOverCellular = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                         .boolForKey("allow_upload_over_cellular")
```

If this is true and I have either Wifi or Cellular internet I allow the upload to proceed.  If this is not true and I have cellular internet I stop the upload.

So this is working nicely and then suddenly I was looking in the settings for my app and I noticed that I have both the **System** level **Cellular Data** option as well as my custom **Use Cellular Data** option. showing up

[image]

### Question

Obviously this *could* cause some confusion for users - I wanted to know if there Is there API access to this system level **Cellualr Data** option - or some other way to control this setting programmatically - I suspect there is not but I'm hoping somebody can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's access to the global cellular data setting, but if you use `NSURLSession` APIs for downloading data, you can create an `NSURLSessionConfiguration` with `allowsCellularAccess = false`.