# Confused over use of allowsCellularAccess

Tags: urlsession

I need some help understanding if I need to use allowsCellularAccess property of the configuration for a URLSession().

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988505/ios-programatic-cellular-data-control/36991940#36991940) iOS already has a setting to control cellular access for apps.

I have added a setting to my app to control allowing cellular  access. I use that setting to assign a value to accessallowsCellularAccess.

But now I am wondering if I really need my own setting. I would be fine with the iOS setting; so, perhaps I just need to remove my setting, ignore accessallowsCellularAccess and let the global iOS setting handle everything.

Looking for suggestions. Thanks!